# JavaScript Extension - marking multiple YouTube videos as "Non-interesting" with mouse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to write a simple little extension with the purpose of:

On YouTube main page the user can click and drag a rectangular box (as on desktop or in any RTS), and all the videos that fit into the box - have their **"3dots"** button clicked, and then **"Not interested"**.

As my professional background has zero web, I started from remembering HTML and CSS structure, and how **JavaScript** can manipulate those.

I made a small extension (manifest and icon etc) with just:

- document.addEventListener('mousedown', mainMouseDownHandler, true);
- document.addEventListener("mouseup", mainMouseUpHandler, true);
- document.addEventListener("mousemove", mainMouseMoveHandler, true);

And inside each function I have put different **console.log**, just to be sure I'm doing it right.

Next I found an example online about how somebody draws with **JavaScript** on "canvas" element. However I do not see "canvas" on **YouTube** page. There are only flex containers inside other flex containers.

It dawned on me that it may be more complex than I have assumed (draw box - click).

Is this idea viable at all, or it's not that trivial for a simple extension?

Example logic:
draw box - click ====
mouse pressed, mouse moved, calculate rectangle and all the components inside of it - get all "3dot menu" component --> "Not interested" button

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There's no need for a canvas usually. Just add your own div with CSS style and resize it in `mousemove` event. This is a popular thing so there should be lots of examples. As for the ultimate functionality see [YT: not interested in one click](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/396936-yt-not-interested-in-one-click) (in your extension you'll need to add code in [page context](/a/9517879) to extract `data` stuff).